How to Add Proxy with Authentication to ChromeDriver in C# for Web Scraping?
I'm trying to use a proxy with authentication in my Selenium WebDriver setup with ChromeDriver in C#. However, I keep encountering the ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES error when trying to navigate to any website. I've tried multiple proxies and different configurations, but nothing seems to work.
Here's what I've tried so far

Setting up the ChromeOptions with the proxy URL including authentication credentials.
Using various proxy servers and different configurations for the proxy settings.
Adding necessary arguments to avoid detection (e.g., disabling GPU, setting user-agents).

Despite these attempts, the error persists.
Here is the relevant part of my code:
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a Random object for generating random delays and user-agents
        var random = new Random();

        // List of user-agents
        var userAgents = new List<string>
        {
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"
           
        };

        // Proxy credentials
        string proxyUsername = "username";
        string proxyPassword = "password";
        string proxyHost = "host";
        int proxyPort = 823;

        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
        proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
        proxy.SslProxy = $"http://{proxyUsername}:{proxyPassword}@{proxyHost}:{proxyPort}";

        // Perform the search 100 times
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            var createOptions = new Func<ChromeOptions>(() =>
            {
                var options = new ChromeOptions();
                // options.AddArgument("--headless"); // Enable headless mode for debugging
                options.AddArgument("--disable-gpu");
                options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
                options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
                options.AddArgument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");

                options.Proxy = proxy;
                options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");

                // Randomize the user-agent
                string userAgent = userAgents[random.Next(userAgents.Count)];
                options.AddArgument($"user-agent={userAgent}");

                // Set other stealth options
                options.AddArgument("lang=en-US");
                options.AddArgument("window-size=1920,1080");

                return options;
            });

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Downloading ChromeDriver...");
                var driverExecutablePath = await new ChromeDriverInstaller().Auto();
                Console.WriteLine($"Using ChromeDriver at: {driverExecutablePath}");

                Console.WriteLine("Starting ChromeDriver...");
                using var driver = UndetectedChromeDriver.Create(
                    driverExecutablePath: driverExecutablePath,
                    options: createOptions(),
                    commandTimeout: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)); // Increased timeout
                Console.WriteLine("ChromeDriver started successfully.");

                // Navigate to a test page to verify proxy settings
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://ident.me");
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                var ipElement = wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(By.TagName("pre")));
                Console.WriteLine($"IP Address: {ipElement.Text}");

                // Navigate to Google
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
                .... 
                Removed for clarity


